# Not getting output in Groovy when execute aws command with "|" and "sed"

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins's Active choice parameter to populate list of RDS instance Type

I am new to groovy and trying to get values of aws cli with sed from groovy script.

Below code works fine, however it gives duplicate entries due to multiple licensing option

```
def command = "aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --engine-version 8.0.20 --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
def instances = proc.in.text.readLines()
return instances
```

To remove duplicate entries I tired below codes but it wont show any output

**First Try**

```
def command = "aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --engine-version 8.0.20 --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text | sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' | sort -u"
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
def instances = proc.in.text.readLines()
return instances
```

**Second Try**

```
def command = """
aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --engine-version 8.0.20 --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text | sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' | sort -u
"""
def proc = ['bash', '-c', command].execute()
proc.waitFor()
def instances = proc.in.text.readLines()
return instances
```

ABove code gave below error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

    at ConsoleScript18.run(ConsoleScript18:9)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Third Try**

```
def  module = sh(script: """aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --engine-version 8.0.20 --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text | sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' | sort -u """,returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "${module}"
```

Give Below error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript26.sh() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[script:aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --engine-version 8.0.20 --query OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass --output text | sed -e 'y/  /
/' | sort -u , ...]]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), NV([Ljava.lang.Object;), run(), run(), any()
```

I would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: 1st cant work because `|` is part of shell. 3d could work only if you are in jenkins pipeline. the 2nd gives you a clear error and `The system cannot find the file specified` sounds like a windows error, but bash is not a part of windows. So, what OS do you have? Are you inside jenkins-pipeline?

Comment: @daggett, We use CentOS 7. I am trying to use it in Jenkin's Active choice Parameter -> Groovy script

Comment: My output is like this `[db.m3.2xlarge, db.m3.2xlarge, db.m3.2xlarge, db.m3.large]` I tried with groovy to remove duplicate if sed not working still getting below error
`def lst = [db.m3.2xlarge, db.m3.2xlarge, db.m3.2xlarge, db.m3.large].unique()` error is `Unexpected input: '.' at line: 2, column: 17`

Comment: in groovy code string must be in quotes or doublequotes: `def lst = ['db.m3.2xlarge', 'db.m3.2xlarge', 'db.m3.2xlarge', 'db.m3.large'].unique()`

Comment: @daggett, Thank you responding. I was able to solved it, posted my answer below so other's can be benefited if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Investing a lot's of time I was able to solve it.

First I was trying to use normal bash utility (i.e. `sed`) so remove duplicates, however it's difficult to use with groovy.

So used groovy's `unique` feature to remove it.

Below my working code for Jenkin's **Active choice parameter** plugin. so If anyone stuck related to these kind of issues can use it.

```
def cmd = "aws rds describe-orderable-db-instance-options --engine mysql --engine-version 8.0.20 --query [OrderableDBInstanceOptions[*].DBInstanceClass] --output text"
def output = cmd.execute()
output.waitFor()
def error = output.err.text
def instances = output.text.tokenize().toUnique()
if (error) {
    return [error]
} else {
    return instances
}
```